# Making dataframe column with named vector

Tags: r

I was planning to make a new column with named vector which can match the names in dataframe, but it seems the matching is not done properly.

Here's an example code

```
vector <- c(APPLE=10,BANANA=2,KIWI=3,CARROT=4,ORANGE=5)

df <- data.frame(fru=c("APPLE","KIWI","CARROT","CARROT","KIWI","ORANGE","BANANA"))
df$num <- vector[df$fru]
```

in this code, the vector is defined like this,

```
 APPLE BANANA   KIWI CARROT ORANGE 
     1      2      3      4      5
```

but in the dataframe, the number corresponding to KIWI and CARROT doesn't match...

```
     fru num
1  APPLE  10
2   KIWI   4
3 CARROT   3
4 CARROT   3
5   KIWI   4
6 ORANGE   5
7 BANANA   2
```

is there any misunderstanding in the way that i make indexing in vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your verbatim code at my RStudio console, and the corresponding numbers for KIWI and CARROTS in `df` match the numbers in `vector` . I don't know how you got different result.

[image]

Comment: can't understand neither ...better try this on another computer... thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the 'fru' column is `factor`.  It needs to be `character` class.

```
vector[as.character(df$fru)]
#  APPLE   KIWI CARROT CARROT   KIWI ORANGE BANANA 
#   10      3      4      4      3      5      2
```

---

From `R 4.0` onwards, by default, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while we create `data.frame` (or read with `read.csv/read.table` etc.).  If the version of `R` is less than 4, then the `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default.  An option is to specify the argument as `FALSE` while constructing the `data.frame` or convert to `character` with `as.character`

Comment: That worked great! My version of R was 3.6.1 as you suggested. As I changed the class of the column, it worked. Thank you!